# Text in file is not printing

Tags: python

I want to print text from a file but the output doesn't show anything.

```
def viewstock():
 replit.clear()
 print ("Here is the current stock\n-------------------------")
 f = open("stock", "a+")
 p = f.read()
 print (p)
 print ("Press enter to return to the stock screen")
 e = input ('')
 if e == '':
   stock_screen()
 else:
   stock_screen()
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why did you open the file in append mode, when you just want to read from it?  I suspect that's leaving the current file position at the very end of the file, where there's nothing to read.

Comment: As jasonharper pointed out, the initial position of the stream in append mode (`"a"` or `"a+"`) is at the end of the file. Which makes sense, if you want to append something to it. You can set the stream back to the beginning of the file with `f.seek(0)` before reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just open the file in `read` mode, and not `append` mode. Try this code:

```
f = open('stock', 'r') -> #(r stands for read mode)
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
f.close()
```

Comment: You can gain reputation through accepting people's answers, its how we say thank you in the Stack Overflow community! :)

Answer (score 0):

To read a file and print, you may want to just open the file in read mode.

```
def viewstock():
    replit.clear()
    print ("Here is the current stock\n-------------------------")
    with open("stock", "r") as f:
        p = f.readlines()
        print (p)
    print ("Press enter to return to the stock screen")

    e = input ('')
    stock_screen()     #You just need to call it once

    #this entire section can be ignored and instead the above line will do
    '''
    The if and else does the same thing. So no need to use if statement
    if e == '':
        stock_screen()
    else:         
        stock_screen()
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from a file open it in ***read*** mode and not ***append*** mode. When you open it in append mode the file's position is at the end where it returns nothing.

try this:

```
def viewstock():
 replit.clear()
 print ("Here is the current stock\n-------------------------")
 f = open("stock", "r")
 p = f.read()
 print (p)
 print ("Press enter to return to the stock screen")
 e = input ('')
 if e == '':
   stock_screen()
 else:
   stock_screen()
```